# derivative of $\sec^2(x/12)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Alright, so [the derivative of $\sec^2(x/12)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20of%20sec%5E2%28x%2F12%29) is $\frac{1}{6} \tan\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) \sec^2\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)$

But if you use chain rule, you get:

$$2  \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)  \left(\sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)\right)'$$
$$2  \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)  \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)  \tan\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)$$

So why do they multiply by the derivative of $\frac{x}{12}$ as well?
I don't get it, what formula do *they* use then?

Comment: Like you said, it's the chain rule. You have treated every part of the function except the $x/12$. I don't know which way you learned the chain rule, but in my mind, I know I have to keep multiplying by derivatives until I am "as far inside as I can go".

Comment: try taking the derivative of $(\frac x2)^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to apply the chain rule again for the second equation on your post. You have $\sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)$, which is a composite. Applying the chain rule, we have

\begin{align}\frac{d}{dx} \left[sec^2\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)\right] &= 2*  \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \frac{d}{dx} \left[\sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)\right] \\
&= 2*  \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \sec\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \tan\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) \\
&= 2*  \sec^2\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \tan\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \frac{1}{12} \\
&= \frac{1}{6} *  \sec^2\left(\frac{x}{12}\right) * \tan\left(\frac{x}{12}\right).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

The reason is exactly what H_T commented:
The angle is not just $x$, but $\frac{x}{12}$. So need to apply one more time the chain rule.
And to provide the final answer, you can group those two $\sec{\left(\frac{x}{12}\right)}$, just like H_T did.

I did not added anything new; just wanted to confirm lol